# c# add a picture to excel from resources

Tags: c#, excel, resources, interop

I'm currently doing the below to add an image to an excel file I'm creating via "interop"

```
private Excel.Workbook _xlWorkBook;
_xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(appPath + @"\ImageFile.png", Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue, 5, 5, 60, 60);
```

I have a couple of questions if I may.

1. How can I access the picture once it's added - e.g. to draw a border on it.
2. Doing the above for my app means that I have to distribute the image file as well so I thought I would put it in the application resources. How do I add the image from the resources to the excel file? Again once added, how do I access it to add border etc?

   _xlWorkSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Properties.Resources.ImageFile); //dosn't work

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.)** I believe you can access the picture by using

```
// after adding the picture
Picture pic = (Picture) ActiveSheet.Pictures(ActiveSheet.Pictures.Count - 1);
pic.Border.LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
pic.Border.Weight = XlBorderWeight.xlMedium;
```

Or

```
// add the picture using Pictures.Insert
// this should return a Picture cast-able object
Picture pic = (Picture) ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(FileName);
// etc...
```

**2.)** The simplest way would be to pull the file from resources write it to a temp file, add it into excel and then remove the temp file.

*This code is very much untested.  Excel interop is a head-ache.*

Comment: thanks for the answer, much appreciated. As for #2 - I've not worked with the resources in that way - would you mind showing me the code needed to achieve #2. Many thanks

Comment: never mind - I've looked into this a bit more. thanks again for the above.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry or the archeology.

For the second question, adding a picture from a ressource, I may have found a solution using the clipboard:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap pic = Properties.Resources.my_ressource;
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetImage(pic);
Range position = (Range)myWorksheet.Cells[Y, X];
myWorksheet.Paste(position); //copy the clipboard to the given position
```

Comment: Thanks Nicolas. This code works but unfortunately it removes the alpha channel case there is any transparency in the image (in this case i tested with a PNG). Do you have some idea to make it work? Thanks advance!

Comment: Transparency wont be captured in clipboard

Answer (score 0):

RE: 2. I did this:

```
S = Shapes.AddPicture(filename,MsoTriState.msoFalse,MsoTriState.msoTrue,0,0,50,50);
S.Name = "Picture";
S.Placement = XlPlacement.xlMoveAndSize;
```