# C# - Clipboard hooking check if the data being copied is really image or a text?

Tags: c#, hook, clipboard

I have a small program that is listening to clipboard(hook) for images. If there is an image stored or copied through ctrl+c and the like, my program will paste the image automatically to an open word doc.

Code:

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
{
  IDataObject obj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
  if (obj.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
   {
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range range = thefile.Bookmarks.get_Item(@"\endofdoc").Range;
   range.Paste();
   newdoc.Selection.EndKey(WdUnits.wdStory);
   }
}
```

I just don't under stand why there are text from a certain application being copied to doc where in fact I'm only looking for bitmap data formats (based on my code). Is there a way to check if the data being copied is really an image or a text? I have no problem doing printscreen but every time I'll copy a text from a certain application (which I believe after doing ctrl+c is now stored in clipboard), the text is being considered an image?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that Clipboard can contain various format data, such as text and bitmap, at the same time.
So, when you run `range.Paste()` and Clipboard contains both text and bitmap data, text data will be copied.

To avoid this unexpected behavior, you need to get image data only from Clipboard by calling `Clipboard.GetImage()` and then paste it to your word doc.

Unfortunately I couldn't find any easy way to do that, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12578760/3522484) might be helpful (i.e. write Clipboard image data to a file and then call `Shapes.AddPicture` to show the image in the word doc).