# How to export excel with image from gridview in c# winform

Tags: c#, excel, windows, winforms, export

I have a database that have an image path but when we export excel from gridview then image should be show in the excel cell where we have attached the image. For example:

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
            Workbook xlWorkBook;
            Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
            object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            int[] ColumnsToInclude = { 0, 1, 16, 7, 8, 19, 9, 10, 17 };
            Int16 i;
            xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
            xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            for (int ix = 0; ix < ColumnsToInclude.Length; ix++)
            {
                xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, ix + 1] = dgvSummaryReport.Columns[ColumnsToInclude[ix]].HeaderText;
            }
            for (i = 0; i <= dgvSummaryReport.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < ColumnsToInclude.Length; j++)
                {
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgvSummaryReport[ColumnsToInclude[j], i].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
            xlWorkBook.SaveAs("H:\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + "_List of ocuupier detail for biometric  survey" + ".xls", XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
            MessageBox.Show("File Created Successfully.in this location.");
            xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
            xlApp.Quit();
            releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
            releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
            releaseObject(xlApp);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strCurrentMethod = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
            strCurrentMethod = this.GetType().Name + " - " + strCurrentMethod;
            ErrorLog.WriteTextFile(strCurrentMethod, ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show("Please check error log.", "ErrorLog", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }enter code here
```

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried, and in what way does it behave differently to what you'd expect?

Comment: I tried how to do it but I am not getting any idea. plz help sir

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried? Please share the code you've already written, we can't find a problem in code we can't see.

Comment: ok we try only export data from gridview we share code......

Comment: I added the code

Comment: OK, we're getting somewhere. I have no experience with Excel interop but I guess your code is putting the path to the image into the spreadsheet rather than inserting an actual image? Does this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12578760/16563198 help? Looks like you might want to investigate `Excel.Worksheet.Shapes.AddPicture`